# How do we compare variable and select right key, value pair accordingly in terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I have 2 ACR's per region and we have multiple regions(AMAP, EU, CN). Now i am writing a terraform code to define a variable acr_region as below

```
variable "acr_regions" {
  type = map
  description = "ACR region"
  default = {
    cne = "cneacr.azurecr.cn"
    cnn = "cnn2acr.azurecr.cn"
    cus = "cusacr.azurecr.io"
    eus2 = "eus2acr.azurecr.io"
    eus = "eusacr.azurecr.io"
    neu = "neuacr.azurecr.io"
    weu = "weuacr.azurecr.io"
  }
}
```

my requirement is if my cluster name includes weu(westeurope), neu, eus etc.. then it should compare acr_region map and pick respective  acr to pull the image.

for ex: if my cluster name is eus.k8s then it should try to pull a image from eus = "eusacr.azurecr.io".

Please do let me know if there is a possibility in terraform to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this split the cluster name `split(".", "eusacr.azurecr.io")` you get a list with 1st index being `eusacr` map key , NOTE: it will only work if cluster name follows this pattern, as i am not aware of azure naming conventions `<acr-region>.<etc>.<etc>`

then you can use lookup to get the corresponding region value `lookup(acr_regions, "eusacr")`

```
locals {
    split_var = split(".", "eusacr.azurecr.io") // cluster name
    acr_region = lookup(var.acr_regions, local.split_var[0])
}
```

use local block to apply transformation

Comment: I did try but didn't work. do you have any further advice.
Here is a list of cluster name. 

variable "scp_clusters" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "SCP cluster list"
  default = ["amap-teusapp07-k8s","amap-teus2app01-k8s"]
}
amap - region
t- test
eus- east US
app - team name